# truth set of the axiom

Tags: logic

Edited to add content

1. If p->q

P is a subset of Q

In other words, the truth set of the cause is a subset of the truth set of the effect.

There is no proof that the axiom is true

no reason to be true

No cause to be true

According to the law of identity, axiom A -> axiom A.

The cause of Axiom A is oneself

in other words,

The axiom has no more root cause and has itself as the cause.

Since I said above that the truth set of causes is a subset of the truth set of effects,

A truth set that has only itself as a subset is an axiom's truth set.

in other words

That set is the empty set

Therefore, the truth set of the axiom is the empty set

2. I think the truth set of the axiom is the empty set.

There is no proof that the axiom is true

So there is nothing that makes an axiom true.

Then, the truth set of the axiom is the empty set?

Comment: NO; the axioms of arithmetic (Peano axioms) are true for natural numbers.

Comment: The formal solution is: a **consistent** set of formulas has a model. Thus, a set of axioms **that is consistent** is TRUE in every "structure" (collection of objects) that is a model of the axioms.

Comment: I think you are confusing truth sets with [truth-makers](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truthmakers/). To have the truth set, a sentence must have free variables, then it is the set of their values which make it true. Axioms, like any propositions, have no free variables and hence no truth sets. Truth-maker is what makes something true. Whether axioms have them depends on the nature of axioms and one's view of them. For platonists, there is "one true math" reflecting some ideal realm and how things are in that realm is what makes true axioms true.

Comment: I think this question is quite interesting, but bad formulated, it should be: _What are axiom systems based upon? Are axiom systems based upon the empty set?_ My answer would be: all axiomatic systems depend on a hierarchy of axiomatic systems until reaching **pure logic**. For example: the axioms of chess depend on the axioms of geometry, arithmetic, etc.; those depend on the axioms of the set theory; this last depend on pure logic (See Kristian Berry's answer: essentially, the axioms that allow `T=~F`). Which IS NOT the empty set.

Comment: All the pseudo-argument is quite confusing... If we stay at your approach the truth set of A is included in the truth set of A and thus A is subset of A, we may agree. But "in other words: That set is the empty set" No. every set is subset of itself: this does not mean that every set is the empty one.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Isn't a set that has only itself as a subset an empty set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical minimal truth-value set is roughly equivalent to {0, {0}} = {0, 1} = {F, T}. Sometimes we might define T = ~F, but we more often hold F and T to be relatively, jointly primitive, *or* we go so far as to declare that F = ~T (though note that F also should = T~, and then if we went the other way, we'd also have T = F~).

Now, the *proof* set of an axiom would be empty, of course, so if one equated justification strictly with proof, one would have that the *justification* set of an axiom is empty, too, and the whole scheme would perhaps fall to the ground. But hardly anyone says such things.

***Further reading (selected examples):***

1. Artemov and Fitting, [Justification Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-justification/)
2. Shramko and Wansing, [Truth Values](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-values/)
3. Moschovakis, [Intuitionistic Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/)
4. Halbach and Leigh, [Axiomatic Theories of Truth](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth-axiomatic/)
5. Hasan and Fumerton, [Foundationalist Theories of Epistemic Justification](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/justep-foundational/)

Comment: Right. Axiomatic systems have no proofs, except pure logical consistency. But It seems to me the question targets far more than truth values: it targets the core axiom system that hosts _truth_ as such, which is pure Logic.